# sql select group by int()

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to get int using this query:

```
    "SELECT int(Abs(x1-x2)+0.5) AS len, Count(*) AS num FROM Coordinates
         GROUP BY int(Abs(x1-x2)+0.5) 
         ORDER BY int(Abs(x1-x2)+0.5) ASC;";
int len = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("len"));
```

But I get double(x1 and x2 type). I'm using Access db. Group by and order by **len** doesn't work.

Comment: try using the func floor/ceil instead of int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `int` and `floor` functions don't change types but just do rounding.
You need `CLng` or `CInt` functions.

> Each function coerces an expression to a specific data type.
>
> Syntax
>
> CBool(expression)
>
> CByte(expression)
>
> CCur(expression)
>
> CDate(expression)
>
> CDbl(expression)
>
> CDec(expression)
>
> CInt(expression)
>
> CLng(expression)
>
> CLngLng(expression) (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.)
>
> CLngPtr(expression)
>
> CSng(expression)
>
> CStr(expression)
>
> CVar(expression)
>
> The required expression argument is any string expression or numeric
>   expression.
>
> Return Types
>
> The function name determines the return type